# Null pointer exception in Spring with hibernate and OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception, mapping

One setter is constantly giving me NullPointerException, and I don't know why. This is the diagram:

[image]

This is the main class:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Registration extends DomainEntity {

    // Constructors -----------------------------------------------------------

    public Registration() {
        super();
    }

    // Attributes -------------------------------------------------------------

    private Date moment;
    private String announcement;

    @NotNull    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Past
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    public Date getMoment() {
        return moment;
    }

    public void setMoment(Date moment) {
        this.moment = moment;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getAnnouncement() {
        return announcement;
    }

    public void setAnnouncement(String announcement) {
        this.announcement = announcement;
    }

    // Relationships ----------------------------------------------------------

    private Payment payment;
    private Customer owner;

    //@Valid
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="registration", optional=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Payment getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(Payment payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
        payment.setRegistration(this);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Customer getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Customer owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

This is the dependent class:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Payment extends DomainEntity {

    // Constructors -----------------------------------------------------------

    public Payment() {
        super();
    }

    // Attributes -------------------------------------------------------------

    private Date moment;
    private Double fee;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    public Date getMoment() {
        return moment;
    }

    public void setMoment(Date moment) {
        this.moment = moment;
    }

    @Digits(fraction=2, integer=2)
    @Min(0)
    public Double getFee() {
        return fee;
    }

    public void setFee(Double fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    // Relationships ----------------------------------------------------------

    private Registration registration;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Registration getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }

    public void setRegistration(Registration registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }

}
```

The information to fill these classes comes from a `form:form` tag. Everything works ok if I put (`optional = false`) in the OneToOne annotation in both classes. However, when I put `optional=true` in the Registration class, the setter "`payment.setRegistration(this)`" in the Registration class, gives me `NullPointerException`, but I'm totally sure, that the payment is not null because I'm printing it to screen before saving the registration. What's the problem then?

EDITED:

Added repository and service layer code:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<Registration, Integer> {

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RegistrationService {

    // Managed repository -----------------------------------------------------

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationRepository registrationRepository;

    // Supporting services ----------------------------------------------------

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    // Constructors -----------------------------------------------------------

    public RegistrationService() {
        super();
    }

    // Simple CRUD methods ----------------------------------------------------

    public Registration createRegistration() {
        Registration result;
        Date moment;
        Customer owner;

        moment = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1);
        owner = customerService.findByPrincipal();

        result = new Registration();    
        result.setMoment(moment);
        result.setOwner(owner);

        owner.addRegistration(result);

        return result;
    }

    public void save(Registration registration) {
        Assert.notNull(registration);

        registrationRepository.save(registration);
    }

    public void delete(Registration registration) {
        Assert.notNull(registration);
        Assert.isTrue(registration.getId() != 0);

        registrationRepository.delete(registration);        
    }

    // Business methods -------------------------------------------------------

    public Collection<Registration> findByPrincipal() {
        Collection<Registration> result;
        Customer customer;

        customer = customerService.findByPrincipal();
        result = customer.getRegistrations();

        return result;
    }

    public void registerPrincipal(Registration registration) {
        Assert.notNull(registration);

        Customer owner;
        Date paymentMoment;
        Date registrationMoment;

        owner = customerService.findByPrincipal();

        registration.setOwner(owner);

        save(registration);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you really have payment withour registration?  `@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` says that you can. Sicne you did not provided stacktrade there is not much we can do. Try changing payment mapping -> change optional to false

Comment: Can you please provide little bit of code where you are persisting entities (code for transaction)

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If I put optional=true in both classes, everything works ok. The correct code would be:

`optional=true -> Registration class`
`optional=false -> Payment class`

Comment: Edited to reflect this change.

Comment: And you dont want to set them to optional right? Well at least one of them has to be NULLable (aka optional) and i would say, payment is optional because you can have registration without payment, but you cannot have payment without registration

Comment: I'm persisting calling `save(Registration registration)` method in `RegistrationRepository` that extends `JpaRepository`

Comment: The diagram is what I'm trying to implement. Registration class is mandatory for Payment class, but Payment class is optional to Registration. That's, a Registration can be created without a Payment

Comment: Please add little service layer and repository layer code.

Comment: Did you try to save `Payment` with set `Registration` not the other way around like you doing now (according to your comment)?

Comment: @Antoniossss I did it. I've put the set in both classes with similar results.

Comment: Ok, one last thing, If you are saying you have NPE on `registrationRepository.save(registration);` than registrationRepository is null. Paste StackTrace.